# Get list of elements where there are two records

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that looks a little like this;

```
id - int
tpc - string
dcid - int
other fields
```

The unique pair in this really `tpc` and `dcid`.  `tpc` can be either LQ or GR at this point.  There may be more coming up but for now it's just two.

So I am looking at getting a list of records, via LINQ, where there are two records with the same dcid, one for LQ and one for GR.

so if I have the following data;

```
1, GR, 1, ...
2, LQ, 1, ...
3, GR, 2, ...
4, GR, 3, ...
5, LQ, 3, ...
```

The returned list I'd like would be 1,2,4,5.
3 would not be in the list as it is missing an LQ entry for dcid 2.

I've tried various queries but am struggling with the logic of checking against two dcid's with the tpc's.

Comment: Have you done a GroupBy on dcid and check where the count > 1?

Comment: I thought of that but tpc might include say a third option one day and i'd hate to have to revisit.  will do if no one responds with a solution and i can't find an adequate one myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var required = new List<string> { "LQ", "GR" };
var query = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.dcid)
    .Where(g => g
        .Select(x => x.tpc)
        .Intersect(required)
        .Count() == required.Count)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it right, you wish to return the ID where a record exists for each of the available TPC types. In your example there are 2 TPC types, but there could be more.

Something like this works:

```
var tpcs = new List<string>();

var filtered = records.GroupBy(record =>
{
  //Keep a track of the available TPC types
  if (!tpcs.Contains(record.TPC))
  {
    tpcs.Add(record.TPC);
  }

  return record.DCID;

})
.Where(group =>
{
  //Get the TPCs for the group
  var groupTpcs = group.Select(record => record.TPC);

  //Only return groups that have records for all the TPC types
  return groupTpcs.Intersect(tpcs).Count() == tpcs.Count;       
});

//Print groups
foreach (var group in filtered)
{
  Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
  foreach (var record in group)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("\tID = {0}, TPC = {1}, DCID = {2}", record.ID, record.TPC, record.DCID);
  }
}
```

Results:

```
1
    ID = 1, TPC = GR, DCID = 1
    ID = 2, TPC = LQ, DCID = 1
3
    ID = 4, TPC = GR, DCID = 3
    ID = 5, TPC = LQ, DCID = 3
```

If you just want the IDs, tack a SelectMany on the end of the LINQ statement

```
.SelectMany(group =>
{
  //Return a list of IDs for each record in the group
  return group.Select(record => record.ID);
});
```

Not sure I'd recommend this approach though.